# Ramda: Extract flat array of uniq values

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I do have a working code like the following, but I am wondering if there is a way with Ramda to turn this whole expression into a curried function where I can specify the input data argument. Perhaps even compose a whole thing differently.

```
const data = [
  { val: ['A', 'B'] },
  { val: ['C', 'D'] },
  { val: ['A', 'C', 'E'] },
]

R.uniq(R.flatten(R.map(R.prop('val'), data)))
```

I tried using `R.__`, but that's probably working differently, not for such nested calls.

Comment: Can't you use the `.compose()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple transformation of your function, using `compose`:

```js
const {compose, uniq, flatten, map, prop} = R;

const data = [
  { val: ['A', 'B'] },
  { val: ['C', 'D'] },
  { val: ['A', 'C', 'E'] },
]

const extract = compose(uniq, flatten, map(prop('val')))

console.log(extract(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

This could also be written with Ramda's order-reversed twin of `compose`, `pipe`:

```js
const {pipe, uniq, flatten, map, prop} = R;

const data = [
  { val: ['A', 'B'] },
  { val: ['C', 'D'] },
  { val: ['A', 'C', 'E'] },
]

const extract = pipe(
  map(prop('val')),
  flatten, 
  uniq
)

console.log(extract(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

I personally choose `compose` for one-liners, `pipe` for anything longer.

The notion of function composition expressed in these two functions is quite central to Ramda. (Disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author.)